# Powershell - Remove AD Contacts if <2

Tags: powershell

Im a bit stuck, how can i filter in powershell if example

```
Get-ADGroupmember X -Filter (LESS THEN 2 MEMBER OF)
```

How can i filter with member of?

I have tried to search for answers but no luck
Thanks

Comment: `Get-ADGroupmember` does not have `-Filter` Parameter, what exactly you trying to do? to find groups with less then 2 members?

Comment: Example:

AD Group with 30 contacts If the 30contacts are member of an other AD Group then i dont want to display them in the search

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to find groups with 2 or less members :

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | % { $a=Get-ADGroupMember $_; if ($a.count -le 2){$_}}
```

or

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Where {(Get-ADGroupMember $_).count -le 2}
```

Comment: I think he's looking for users that are members of two or less groups.